# rsync from 1 ec2 instance to another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have 2 ec2 instances, I am able to login ssh to both through winscp.
I have ppk for instance 2 but not the pem file.
I have both ppk and pem file for instance 1.
I want to transfer my files from instance 1 to 2 and I issue this command through instance 1 in linux console

```
rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -avl --exclude-from '/ex.txt' /PATH/* bitnami@IP:/PATHs/ >> /tmp/rsync_update.txt
```

and it says

```
Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

anyone who can tell me what I am missing here,

Answer (score 0):

Instance 1 needs to have a keypair configured to allow it to access instance 2. There is no need to use the same keypair, and it might be somewhat better to generate a key for instance 1.

The steps are pretty simple. Use `ssh-keygen` to generate a keypair on instance 1. Just allow it to be saved in the default location (usually the .ssh folder of the current user's home directory).

If you used the default settings, your public key for the newly generated keypair will be in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Copy the contents of this file into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on instance 2.

Comment: how can I get the pem key of an instance, if I have the ppk and I am logged in through putty